# User control within User control within Master Page and setting a property c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webusercontrol

How do I get/set a property within a User Control inside User Control within Master Page in c# ?

Example structure:

- Web User Control **'WebUserControlA.ascx'**
- Web User Control **'WebUserControlB.ascx'**
- Master Page **'Content.master'**
- Web Form Page **'Test.aspx'**

**'Test.aspx'**, is a content page from the **'Content.master'** page, it includes:

```
 <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Content.master" %>
```

The **content.master** page includes the **'WebUserControlA.ascx'** and in    **'WebUserControlA.ascx'** is **'WebUserControlB.ascx'** included.

I wish to be able to set text of a *label control* in the **'WebUserControlB.ascx'** from the **'Test.aspx'** code behind file.

**UPDATED NOTES:**

After receiving a potential answer from 'VDWWD', which allowed me to set the text label, I need to expand my original question:

"I would like to control a get/set a property within the code behind of the **WebUserControlB.ascx** so that I'm able to display content from the database correctly, for example I want to pass in a country code from the code behind of **test.aspx** to the WebUserControlB.ascx code behind"

```
 public string CountryCode { get; set; }
```

I have tried the following however was not able to get hold of the get/set property:

```
 UserControl WebControlB = (UserControl)Page.Master.FindControl("WebUserControlA").FindControl("WebUserControlB");
 if (WebControlB != null) {
     WebControlB.CountryCode = "[CODE]";
 }
```

When trying to do this i get the following error:

> 'UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'CountryCode' and no
>   extension method 'CountryCode' accepting a first argument of type
>   'UserControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Thanks for helping

Comment: Use FindControl `ControlA.FinControl("ControlB").FindControl("ControlC")`

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm, however i have expanded my original query of my original post. thanks

Comment: You have to cast the object to the correct type `var controlB = ControlA.FinControl("ControlB") as UserControl1` Where UserControl1 is the class name.